# White Screen after npm run build React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, web-applications, react-router

I have created a react app using create-react-app. It runs fine when i do
`npm start`. But after i build the project using `npm run build` and open the `index.html` it throws a white screen.

Relavent codes given below. Please help me to find out the issue.

App.js

```
<React.StrictMode>
 <BrowserRouter>
  <Router />
 </BrowserRouter>
</React.StrictMode>
```

Router.js

```
<Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/dashboard" replace />} ></Route>
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />}></Route>
        <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp />}></Route>
        <Route element={<Layout />}>
            <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />}></Route>
            <Route path="/insert" element={<Insert />}></Route>
            <Route path="/payments" element={<Payments />}></Route>
            <Route path="/transactions" element={<Transactions />}></Route>
            <Route path="/generate-invoice" element={<UserMerchantGenerateInvoice/>}></Route>
            <Route exact path="/user-upgrade" element={<UserUpgrade/>}></Route>
            <Route path="/user-merchant-pay" element={<UserMerchantPay />}></Route>

        </Route>
    </Routes>
```

Package.json

```
"version": "0.1.0",
  "private": false,
  "homepage": ".",
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <App />
);
```

index.html(on build folder)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="./logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json" />
    <title>React App</title>
    <script defer="defer" src="./static/js/main.160e0e1d.js"></script>
    <link href="./static/css/main.0d9d8db6.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: If not CORS issue, maybe you are trying to access `//dashboard` ? I haven't found `Navigate` component inside React router, what library are you using, and if that's a component of yours, what is inside ? Otherwise maybe try to use [Redirect](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect).

---

Are you using a web server to view your `index.html` page ? You can use [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve).

```bash
npm i -D serve
```

In `package.json`

```json
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "serve build -l 3001"
  },
```

```bash
npm run serve
```

Open http://localhost:3001/ .

Check your console tab, the issue you are facing is [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Comment: Not need to build the project and create a build folder. npm run serve and npm start works fine.

Comment: @DineshKumar I updated my answer, I overlooked you had send some code about Routing.

Comment: using react-router-dom , serve is not what i need. I need to run the script npm run build and create a working index.html. for me serve -s build -l 80 and npm start works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using react-router and trying to open index.html directly in the browser (or using electron, which essentially does that), in addition to setting homepage as others have suggested, replace your BrowserRouter with a HashRouter.